# Outputs of rolling multiple dies and time complexity

Tags: java, recursion, dice

I am working on this problem which seems very straigtforward:

> For n number of dies return all the permutations. 
> Eg. n = 1, output = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]] 
> Eg. n = 2, output = [[1, 1],[1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 4],[1, 5],[1, 6], [2, 1], ..... [6, 6]]

So I have solved it using recursion where the current solution uses previous results and builds on it:

```
public class Dice {

    private static List<List<Integer>> getCombinations(int n) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // base cases
        if (n == 0) {
            return result;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(i);
                result.add(list);
            }
        }

        // general case
        List<List<Integer>> prevResult = getCombinations(n - 1);
        for (List<Integer> prevlist: prevResult){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(prevlist);
                list.add(i);
                result.add(list);
            }
        }

        memo.put(n, result);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("val = " + getCombinations(4));
    }

}
```

I wanted to ask if I am right about the time complexity, which I think would be:

```
Time Complexity = O(b^d)
where b=branching factor and d=depth of recursion tree
                 = O(6^n)
```

Is this right?

Also I had 2 additional questions:

1. Is there a way I can memoize the above to reduce the time complexity?
2. Is there another better algorithm that I can use to solve this?

Comment: You can't reduce the time complexity, because the output itself is O(b^d). If order doesn't matter, there are more efficient solutions (though still exponential in nature).

Comment: Are `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` considered different permutations?

Comment: Yes, `[1, 2] and [2, 1]` are different as per the problem statement. However, what improvement could be done if that was not the case?

Comment: I can sort each list before putting it in the result, and the result could be a Set. But the result will still be calculated in this case so won't improve anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an iterative approach rather than recursive, you could consider using a [**`Deque`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html):

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.List;

/** Prints the permutations of rolling N dice with M faces. */
final class DiceRollPermutations {

  private DiceRollPermutations() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: java DiceRollPermutations <numDice> <numFaces>");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    int numDice = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int numFaces = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    Deque<List<Integer>> diceRollPermutations = getDiceRollPermutations(numDice, numFaces);
    System.out.printf(
        "All possible permutations (%d) for rolling %d %s with %d %s:%n",
        diceRollPermutations.size(),
        numDice,
        numDice == 1 ? "die" : "dice",
        numFaces,
        numFaces == 1 ? "face" : "faces");
    for (List<Integer> permutation : diceRollPermutations) {
      System.out.println(permutation);
    }
  }

  public static Deque<List<Integer>> getDiceRollPermutations(int numDice, int numFaces) {
    Deque<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayDeque<>();
    permutations.offer(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDice; i++) {
      int numPermutations = permutations.size();
      for (int j = 1; j <= numPermutations; j++) {
        List<Integer> perm = permutations.pollFirst();
        for (int k = 1; k <= numFaces; k++) {
          List<Integer> permClone = new ArrayList<>(perm);
          permClone.add(k);
          permutations.offer(permClone);
        }
      }
    }
    return permutations;
  }
}
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
$ java DiceRollPermutations 2 6
All possible permutations (36) for rolling 2 dice with 6 faces:
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 6]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[3, 6]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
[4, 5]
[4, 6]
[5, 1]
[5, 2]
[5, 3]
[5, 4]
[5, 5]
[5, 6]
[6, 1]
[6, 2]
[6, 3]
[6, 4]
[6, 5]
[6, 6]
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
$ java DiceRollPermutations 3 6
All possible permutations (216) for rolling 3 dice with 6 faces:
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 6]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 6]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 1]
[1, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 4]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 5, 1]
[1, 5, 2]
[1, 5, 3]
[1, 5, 4]
[1, 5, 5]
[1, 5, 6]
[1, 6, 1]
[1, 6, 2]
[1, 6, 3]
[1, 6, 4]
[1, 6, 5]
[1, 6, 6]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 4]
[2, 1, 5]
[2, 1, 6]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 5]
[2, 2, 6]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 3]
[2, 4, 4]
[2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 5, 1]
[2, 5, 2]
[2, 5, 3]
[2, 5, 4]
[2, 5, 5]
[2, 5, 6]
[2, 6, 1]
[2, 6, 2]
[2, 6, 3]
[2, 6, 4]
[2, 6, 5]
[2, 6, 6]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 4]
[3, 1, 5]
[3, 1, 6]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 4]
[3, 2, 5]
[3, 2, 6]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 5]
[3, 3, 6]
[3, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 3]
[3, 4, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 6]
[3, 5, 1]
[3, 5, 2]
[3, 5, 3]
[3, 5, 4]
[3, 5, 5]
[3, 5, 6]
[3, 6, 1]
[3, 6, 2]
[3, 6, 3]
[3, 6, 4]
[3, 6, 5]
[3, 6, 6]
[4, 1, 1]
[4, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 3]
[4, 1, 4]
[4, 1, 5]
[4, 1, 6]
[4, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 2, 3]
[4, 2, 4]
[4, 2, 5]
[4, 2, 6]
[4, 3, 1]
[4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 3]
[4, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 5]
[4, 3, 6]
[4, 4, 1]
[4, 4, 2]
[4, 4, 3]
[4, 4, 4]
[4, 4, 5]
[4, 4, 6]
[4, 5, 1]
[4, 5, 2]
[4, 5, 3]
[4, 5, 4]
[4, 5, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[4, 6, 1]
[4, 6, 2]
[4, 6, 3]
[4, 6, 4]
[4, 6, 5]
[4, 6, 6]
[5, 1, 1]
[5, 1, 2]
[5, 1, 3]
[5, 1, 4]
[5, 1, 5]
[5, 1, 6]
[5, 2, 1]
[5, 2, 2]
[5, 2, 3]
[5, 2, 4]
[5, 2, 5]
[5, 2, 6]
[5, 3, 1]
[5, 3, 2]
[5, 3, 3]
[5, 3, 4]
[5, 3, 5]
[5, 3, 6]
[5, 4, 1]
[5, 4, 2]
[5, 4, 3]
[5, 4, 4]
[5, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 6]
[5, 5, 1]
[5, 5, 2]
[5, 5, 3]
[5, 5, 4]
[5, 5, 5]
[5, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 1]
[5, 6, 2]
[5, 6, 3]
[5, 6, 4]
[5, 6, 5]
[5, 6, 6]
[6, 1, 1]
[6, 1, 2]
[6, 1, 3]
[6, 1, 4]
[6, 1, 5]
[6, 1, 6]
[6, 2, 1]
[6, 2, 2]
[6, 2, 3]
[6, 2, 4]
[6, 2, 5]
[6, 2, 6]
[6, 3, 1]
[6, 3, 2]
[6, 3, 3]
[6, 3, 4]
[6, 3, 5]
[6, 3, 6]
[6, 4, 1]
[6, 4, 2]
[6, 4, 3]
[6, 4, 4]
[6, 4, 5]
[6, 4, 6]
[6, 5, 1]
[6, 5, 2]
[6, 5, 3]
[6, 5, 4]
[6, 5, 5]
[6, 5, 6]
[6, 6, 1]
[6, 6, 2]
[6, 6, 3]
[6, 6, 4]
[6, 6, 5]
[6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is good to know. This will have the same time complexity though, right?

Comment: Yes, but there are reasons you might want to use an iterative approach over a recursive approach and vice-versa.

Comment: Any inherent benefit? Wondering since the space and time complexity will be unchanged.